# Problems with call forwarding and MMI return status to a variable (*#21#)

Tags: android-intent

I'm having trouble catching the "result" of *#21# code in my cellphone.  I want to see whether I have call fowarding active or not and store this in a Boolean variable.

Here is my code:

```
public void verificarStatus()
{
     tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
     Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
     Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", "*#21#", "#");
     intentCallForward.setData(uri);
     startActivity(intentCallForward);
     tvStatus.setText();
}
```

Comment: English, formatting, removed extraneous code markup attribute

Comment: Remove irrelevant 'Call' tag